# Display not recognized

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a Waveshare 7inch HDMI LCD (C) touch display, but it is not recognized by my PC at all (touch via USB works, however).

- I changed the HDMI cable: no effect.
- I tried another monitor: works fine.
- I plugged the Waveshare display into my laptop: works fine.

Therefore the display seems to be OK. The computer seems to work. Just they don't seem to like each other.

**Setup**

- Mainboard: [Gigabyte GA-J1900N-D3V](http://www.gigabyte.de/Motherboard/GA-J1900N-D3V-rev-1x#ov)

  - CPU: Intel® Celeron™ J1900 (onboard)
  - graphics: onboard
- Display: [Waveshare 7inch HDMI LCD (C) touch display](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C))
- Connection: DVI-D (board) to HDMI (display)
- OS: Windows 10 (shouldn't be *that* relevant, for any BIOS/startup stuff ain't displayed as well!)

Any ideas? I'm running out of any...

NOTE: I do not see *anything* on the display – even when the computer starts.

Comment: I think we need some more information about the hardware and software you are using. Can you let us know what the specifications of the computer are and specifically what graphics processor you are using? Also, make sure you're not using your motherboard's onboard HDMI port without having a CPU with graphics processor installed. This is a common mistake.

Comment: @AdmiralFreebee, I specified my hardware setup. Please let me know, if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BIOS setting was wrong!

The `Video` mode was set to `Legacy only`. When I set it to `UEFI first` and restart, the display works.